# How to rerender a React component once mounted without calling setState in componentDidMount

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react component wrapped in a HOC that passes props to the wrapped child. When the child's constructor is called it does some work and then it executes a callback passed down in props from the HOC. This callback updates properties in the HOC constructor (definitions)(I think this is the correct language). The HOC then uses the updated definitions to setup subscriptions for both the HOC and its wrapped child.

The reason I am doing this is the child receives props from its parent that contains a dynamic array of objects that requires subscriptions while the component is mounted and there is no way to know what these subscriptions are when the HOC is instantiated.

The HOC is calling setState, which rerenders the child, however, I understand this is an anti-pattern. How could I solve this?

**HOC**

```
const HOCComponent= function HOCComponent(config) {
  return function returnWrapped(Wrapped) {
    return class Wrapper extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        this.handleData = this.handleData.bind(this)
        this.data = {}
      }

      comonentDidMount() {
        setSubscription(this.data, () => {
          this.setState({
            key: getData(),
          })
        })
      }

      handleData(data) {
        this.data = data
      }
      render () {
        <Wrapped handleData={this.handleData} /> 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**CHILD**

```
const Component class Wrapper extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    // Stuff with props received from it's parent (not HOC)       
    props.handleData(props.data)
  }
  render() {
    <div>Hello!</div>
  }
}
```

Comment: Why you don't want to call `setState`?

Comment: I'm calling setState now and it works great. My understanding as state above is this is bad and shouldn't be done, so I am wondering what and if there is a proper way to do this. I absolutely need to call setState though because the HOC's state needs to be updated with data that gets passed through as props, that doesn't exist as the subscription have not yet been called. It's an initial "get" of data that after mounting, is handled by subscriptions.

Comment: _this is bad and shouldn't be done_ Could you explain why because as per my understanding `setState` makes sense here.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`forceUpdate`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#forceupdate) method.

Within the component if you call `this.forceUpdate()` the component will be re-rendered.

Comment: The React docs state: Normally you should try to avoid all uses of forceUpdate()?

Comment: @Kainan Yes, that is normally because you want to use `setState` and use the normal React concepts such as state and props. It just has to do with best practice. Also according to the docs `shouldComponentUpdate` will be skipped. Which could be another reason to avoid it. But given the right situation it can be used.

Comment: @CharlieFish OP is already using `setState` and I don't think `forceUpdate` will provide any benefit over `setState` in this question.